# Twitter Codebird.php - Simple Tweet Function Not Working

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter

For the life of me I cannot figure out why this is not working. The permissions of the oauth app are set to read write. I double checked to make sure the keys were in the correct spots and were correct; I even regenerated new keys. I've also tried both relative and direct links to the codebird.php file which is located in the same directory as my functions file.

```
function code_bird(){
        // require codebird
require_once('codebird.php');

\Codebird\Codebird::setConsumerKey("ConsumerKey", "ConsumerSecret");
$cb = \Codebird\Codebird::getInstance();
$cb->setToken("AccessToken", "Access Secret");

$params = array(
  'status' => 'test'
);
$reply = $cb->statuses_update($params);
}
```

The function is on a test page and should call the function when the page loads.

```
<?php code_bird(); ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm not too familiar with codebird, but it seems like it should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Is your error reporting on? `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: No errors, it's just sending a tweet.

Comment: Can you `print_r($reply);` and show what it returns?

Comment: Doesn't return anything.

Comment: Decided to use a different twitter framework instead of codebird, and the new one works perfectly.

Comment: @nickyb which one?